AAD B2C SAML custom policies, How to add redirectino to a website after a successful authenticate,new site will receive all the SAML attributes
we have succssfully implemented SAML integration with Azure AD B2C using custom policies
We followed MS documentations to add the redirect url on the registred APP but it is not working
I added an extra line to the SigninSignup custom policy like below
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="redirect_uri" DefaultValue="https://website.com" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"/>
I added the below ClaimType to the trustframeworkbase custom policy
<ClaimType Id="redirect_uri">         <DisplayName>Redirect URI</DisplayName>         <DataType>string</DataType>         <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>         <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="redirect_uri" />         <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="redirect_uri" />         </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>         <UserHelpText>URL to redirect to after authentication</UserHelpText>       </ClaimType> 
I also added a below ClaimType to the TrustFrameworkextension
<ClaimsProvider>      <DisplayName>Set Redirect URI Provider</DisplayName>      <TechnicalProfiles>       <TechnicalProfile Id="SetRedirectUriTechnicalProfile">        <DisplayName>Set Redirect URI</DisplayName>        <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>        <OutputClaims>         <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="redirect_uri" DefaultValue="https://website.com" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true"/>        </OutputClaims>       </TechnicalProfile>      </TechnicalProfiles>     </ClaimsProvider> 
With all the above the user is still not being redirected to the website.com I am setting in the redirecting url
Any help is appreciated as I exhuasted the options to go with Microsoft support
Followed all MS documentations to add a redirection link but didnt work added redirection on the registered app

redirectURL is an OIDC concept.
You need to configure the "ACS Endpoint - Assertion Consumer Service URL - often referred to simply as the SP sign-in URL.
This is the endpoint provided by the SP where SAML responses are posted.
The SP needs to provide this information to the IdP".
Update
You can add relayState to the URL and get the result back using claims resolvers.

Thanks
I think I need to use relaystate here but I need some help with examples of using relaystate parameters in an SP initiated authentication (where can I add the relaystate url)
